# By default the 1st accordion should be set to open without clicking on it in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hey guys i need help in solving this problem. I have made use of *ngFor loop for accordion and in this i need the first accordion to be open by default. Can anyone please help me with this. Here is my Angular2 code.

```
<div class="today col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <md-card *ngFor="let value of timer_entries.entries" style="padding:0px !important;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-top: 15px;">
            <div class="accordion-section">
                <accordion>
                    <accordion-group #group>
                        <div accordion-heading>
                            {{value[0]}}
                            <i class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" [ngClass]="{'closeArrow': group?.isOpen, 'openArrow': !group?.isOpen}"></i>
                            <span class="pull-right padding-right-20 color-primary">{{value[2]}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" st-table="rowCollection" class="table table-hover" layout-align="center">
                            <tbody class="table_body" layout-align="center">
                                <tr class="table-content wd_table_row" *ngFor="let d of value[1]">
                                    <td class="date-cell">{{d.times[0].date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                                    <td class="location-cell">{{d.department}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="category-cell">{{d.category}}</td>
                                    <td class="subcategory-cell">{{d.subcategory}}</td>
                                    <td class="client-cell">{{d.client}}</td>
                                    <td class="project-cell">{{d.project}}</td>
                                    <td class="duration-cell">{{d.total_hours}}</td>
                                    <td class="icon-cell-one" style="cursor:pointer;">
                                        <img class="wd-reload-icon" style="width:16px;" src="/images/icons/refreshIcon.svg" alt="reload">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="icon-cell-one" style="cursor:pointer;" (click)="editModal.show()">
                                        <img style="width:16px;" src="/images/icons/pencil-new.svg" alt="edit">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="icon-cell-two" style="cursor:pointer;" (click)="deleteModal.show()">
                                        <img style="width:16px;" src="/images/icons/delete-new.svg" alt="delete">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </accordion-group>
                </accordion>
            </div>
        </md-card>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

Add index to your loop

```
<md-card *ngFor="let value of timer_entries.entries; let i = index" style="padding:0px !important;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-top: 15px;">
```

Now you can add class `open` to your `0th` index's accordion like

```
[ngClass]="{'open':(i==0)}"
```

Comment: please replace `open` class name with your actual class name which opens the accordion